# how to convert jQuery to html & css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a student and I have a question, how to convert this jquery code to html and css inline. Sorry for my bad English and thank you for your kind of support.

```
var d = $('<div />'),
    p = $('<p />');

$('#test')
    .find('div')
    .eq(0)
    .append(d
        .addClass('test')
        .css({
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100,
            'background': '#ccc'
        })
        .append(p.text('test'))
    )
    .next()
    .append(d
        .clone()
        .removeClass('test')
        .addClass('test2')
        .css({
            'width': 200,
            'height': 200,
            'background': '#000'
        })
        .append(p
            .clone()
            .text('test2')
            .css('color', '#FFF')
        )
    );
```

- **note #test is the attribute in `<div>` and this element contents
  with 2 tag `'<div>'`**

Comment: @guest271314: you ruined the code!

Comment: @AHBagheri How so?

Comment: code was shocking originally, now it's abysmal

Comment: Look at the html code!

Comment: dat encoding tho. How does it even happen? For future reference

Comment: The `html` entities are not quoted.  Are you trying to render literal `html` tags as text?

Comment: I hope that's more readable now

Comment: @JaromandaX Initially interpreted Question as OP was trying to render `html` tags. Not sure what issue is with `javascript` at updated Question?

Comment: @Borishi What do you mean by "inline"?

Comment: @guest271314 - I'm guessing OP didn't know how to put code into question

Comment: @JaromandaX Possible, though how and why did OP derive `html` entity references passed to `jQuery()`?

Comment: what? I think he just wants to **not use** jquery  - that's it ... `var d = $('<div>')` is just like `var d = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: @JaromandaX Reviewed revisions. Did not notice second portion of original Question. Though curious why the `html` entities were part of original post.

Comment: @AHBagheri Ok, got it. Apparently missed an entire half of the Question, or viewing something different at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One interpretation of your question seems to be that you want to grab the html produced by it

After your code runs, `$(#test).html()` is probably what you want

```js
var d = $('<div />'),
    p = $('<p />');

$('#test')
    .find('div')
    .eq(0)
    .append(d
        .addClass('test')
        .css({
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100,
            'background': '#ccc'
        })
        .append(p.text('test'))
    )
    .next()
    .append(d
        .clone()
        .removeClass('test')
        .addClass('test2')
        .css({
            'width': 200,
            'height': 200,
            'background': '#000'
        })
        .append(p
            .clone()
            .text('test2')
            .css('color', '#FFF')
        )
    );
    console.log($('#test').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: CSS stylings missing as asked in question and class test2 needs to be added for some div

Comment: `style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: rgb(204, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"` - looks like inline CSS to me, champ ... `<div class="test2"` I see class test2 there ... did you look at the output?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a script tag

```
     <script type="text/javascript">//your code here</script>
```

You are gonna have to specify path for jQuery too for importing the jQuery libraries like this:

```
     <head>
     <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     </head>"
```